# What's the best way to replace text in round brackets with the same text in square brackets?

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I'm trying to do a global find/replace of strings like `('id')` with `['id']` using sed on a Mac. I'm having trouble putting together the correct regex to correctly match the brackets without causing syntax errors. I'm also not necessarily interested in using sed, it just seemed like the best way to do it.

I've tried the following code:

`sed -i "" "s/(['].*['])/[\1]/g" file.txt`

and

`sed -i "" "s/[(]['].*['][)]/[\1]/g" file.txt`

How should I approach this?

Comment: please add sample lines from the file... particularly add a case if a simple `tr '()' '[]'` or `sed 'y/()/[]/'` won't work

Comment: Try `sed -i "" "s/(\('[^']*'\))/[\1]/g" file.txt`. I understand that there are no `'` inside the `('` and `')`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew put your comment in an answer and you can get some upvotes :) It worked, BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no `'` in between `('` and `')` you may use

```
sed "s/(\('[^']*'\))/[\1]/g"
```

The point is that the capturing groups in BRE POSIX regex patterns must be declared with `\(...\)`, while `(` and `)` denote literal `(` and `)` symbols. `[^']*` matches zero or more symbols other than `'`.

**POSIX BRE pattern details**:

- `(` - a literal `(` symbol
- `\('[^']*'\)` - a capturing group matching:

  - `'`  - a single quote
  - `[^']*` - a negated bracket expression matching zero or more  (`*`) chars other than `'` and then
  - `'` - a single quote
- `)` - a literal `)` symbol.

Comment: Yeah, POSIX BRE uses just the opposite escaping rules with capturing groups and range quantifiers, unlike in the usual modern regex. It is easy to get confused.

Answer (score 0):

How robust do you need the script to be? are all of the examples a single set of parentheses or are some nested? Nested may be possible to do in practice, is provably hard to do robustly in sed. Should we account for having parentheses in strings & not replacing them? If so you've got quite a rabbit hole to go down/may be impossible.

Here's a reasonably simple one that assumes the simplest case:

```
sed 's/(\([^)]*\))/[\1]/g' test.tmp
```

### Explanation:

```
sed 's/<find>/<replace>/g'
```

The `sed` substitute command searches for a regular expression within each line and replaces it as specified. The `g` option indicates a 'global' replacement meaning it replaces all occurances on a line, not just the first.

```
(\([^)]*\))
```

The outside parentheses match those you're hoping to replace. The inside escaped parentheses, `\(` and `\)`, create a group around the text you want to keep. `[^)]` matches any character that is not a `)`, while the following `*` tells us to match 0+ such characters.

```
[\1]
```

The `\1` represents the contents of the first (and only) group we formed earlier, and we then place the desired square brackets around it.

Any text not matched by the regular expression remains untouched.